# Jquery masonry doesn't load when accesed via navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-masonry

i'm quite new in ruby on rails developing, i'm learning everyday. I am experiencing a very strange issue.

I use the Masonry Jquery plugin to stylish my app, everything is working fine on chrome, but when i use firefox, safari i'm experiencing issues.

I have to refresh the page to load the jquery plugin, and when i acces the page from my navbar links it doesn't load de the script.

Here is my code jquery code:

```
$('#masonry-container').ready ->
$('#masonry-container').imagesLoaded ->
$('#masonry-container').masonry
isFitWidth: true
```

The thing is that when i access the page typing the url, the script load, when i access the page via my navbar the script doesn't load.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Big thanks guys

Comment: Seems strange that this is only happening in certain browsers. Is there any errors or warnings in the browser console? Also are you using any gems like pjax to load content, which might explain the issue

Comment: @JonDay No i am not using any gems like pjax... also there is no special warnings in the browser console. The thing that i don't understand is that the masonry jquery load when i am typing the url in my browser; but not when i'm accessing the page via the link in my navbar :X

Comment: Hi, just to let you know that i fixed, the problem was with turbolinks gem, i added the jquery-turbolinks gem and this fixed my problem. thanks.